# React Router: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am getting this error while following React Router Tutorial [HERE](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) and [HERE](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/03-navigating-with-link)

It should work as it's supposed to do, because in index.html i have added "app" as id in a div container.

```
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
     ./src/index.js
     src/index.js:15
```

Here is INDEX.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import About from './modules/About'
import Repos from './modules/Repos'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
     </ul>

     <hr/>
     <App />
     <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
     <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
     <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
   </div>
 </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
       <title>My First React Router App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how have you created the bundle.js file and can you make sure that if its present in your folder, the path is correctly mentioned in the index.html

Comment: You can't run React directly on browser, first you need to compile it with babel presets for react. Try create react app, this will help : https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue-
My src/index.js looking like this-

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />,routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I moved all routes in a variable such as `routing` and now code in src/index.js file looks like-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import About from './pages/abouts/about';
import Contact from './pages/contacts/contact';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </div>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

So, no need to pass `<App/>` any more in ReactDOM and that worked for me.

Comment: Just check in your index.html root element exists ?